# Is it possible to write an equivalent of SMSSecure for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone

Is there an API for any version of Windows Phone that allows an application to sniff incoming SMS messages and transparently send ones, replacing the built-in SMS application with one that supports encryption like an Android's [SMSSecure](https://smssecure.org/) does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override basic apps on Windows Phone. You can't modify Contacts, Photos, Messages, Calendar...

If you want to send a SMS message you can use these lines of code:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage msg = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
msg.Body = "Hello d33tah. Nice to see you on stackoverflow!";
msg.Recipients.Add("10086");
msg.Recipients.Add("10010");
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(msg);
```

You can read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn391804.aspx) in order to get more information.